# Kivy how to use FileBrowser properly inside of a popup

Tags: python, kivy

I am looking for a way to create a popup box with a filebrowser inside of it by clicking a button from the main app screen. The below snippet is the class that is called when the upload button is clicked from the main app. It will render the popup with the file browser, but the on_* kwargs do not run the respective methods.

```
class UploadPopup:
    def __init__(self, short_text='heading'):

        browser = FileBrowser(select_string='Select', cancel_state='down')
        browser.bind(on_success=self._fbrowser_success,
                     on_canceled=self._fbrowser_canceled,
                     on_submit=self._fbrowser_submit)

        self.popup = Popup(
            title=short_text,
            content=browser, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9),
            auto_dismiss=False
        )
        self.popup.open()

    def _fbrowser_canceled(self, instance):
        print('cancelled, Close self.')
        self.popup.dismiss()

    def _fbrowser_success(self, instance):
        print(instance.selection)
        self.popup.dismiss()

    def _fbrowser_submit(self, instance):
        print(instance.selection)
        self.popup.open()
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where ever you are calling `UploadPopup()`, you need to save a reference to it, so that it does not get garbage collected. For example, you might want to do `self.pop = UploadPopup()` in your main app.

Also, in your event handling methods, you probably want to replace `self.popup.open()` with `self.popup.dismiss()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I did have the popup subclass a threading.Thread class and run it as a daemon without success prior to asking the question. I will test your suggestion though!

Would you care to work up an example of working code?

Also, I edited the original snippet to reflect the dismiss method, thanks for correcting me, I was a bit hasty when pasting stuff I suppose.

Comment: Could you point me to any documentation that helped you with learning python garbage collection? If not, thanks for the answer anyways!

Comment: The main fact to keep in mind is that when any object can no longer be referenced (for example, a variable that goes out of scope), it is eligible to be garbage collected. In your code below `this = UploadPopup()` creates a variable that references your `UploadPopup` instance, but as soon as that `upload` method ends, the `this` variable and the `UploadPopup` instance are unreachable and will be garbage collected. This [documentation](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001537/references/r_python_garbage_coll.htm) gives a good overview.

Answer (score 1):

I have already accepted an answer, but would like to expand on that a bit. @john-anderson was correct in that garbage collection was collecting the instantiation. I was originally doing this...

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def upload(self):
        this = UploadPopup()
    ...

class UploadPopup():
    ....
    see original post
    ....
```

In order to resolve this issue I had to instantiate in the init method of my MainScreen class add an open method to the UpdatePopup class and call that method when the button was clicked.

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        self.upload_popup = UploadPopup()
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def upload(self):
        self.upload_popup.start()
    ...

class UploadPopup:
    def __init__(self, short_text='heading'):

        browser = FileBrowser(select_string='Select', cancel_state='down')
        browser.bind(on_success=self._fbrowser_success,
                     on_canceled=self._fbrowser_canceled,
                     on_submit=self._fbrowser_submit)

        self.popup = Popup(
            title=short_text,
            content=browser, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9),
            auto_dismiss=False
        )

    def start(self):
        self.popup.open()
    ....
```